# Catchall rewrite rule after 1:1 301 redirect stops 1:1 redirect from working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am implementing a 1:1 redirect in htaccess with something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /1.html site.com/folder/1
Redirect 301 /2.html site.com/2
Redirect 301 /3 site.com/vw-vans/another-folder/2
Redirect 301 /3.html site.com/3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(html)
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)$ site.com/folder? [R=301]
```

What I was expecting here was if 1.html matches it will be redirected to site.com/folder/1 and not site.com/folder. But unless I remove the rewrite rule, that is what is happening. Even with a 'L' flag.

Is it not possible or am I doing something wrong if I want the 1:1 redirect to work and if an url is not part of those 1:1 redirects, it will then apply the rewrite condition. I don't think there is a [L] flag for the 'Redirect' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rules and `mod_rewrite` one as they both get invoked at different times by Apache.

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^1\.html$ /folder/1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^2\.html$ /2 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^3\.html$ /3 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^3/?$ /vw-vans/another-folder/2 [R=301,L,NC]

# catchall rule for .html files
RewriteRule ^.+?\.html$ /folder? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Ahh I did not know that. Does this mean I should not be doing something like this either:

# Redirect PDFs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(pdf)
RewriteRule ^(.+\.pdf)$ site.com/pdf [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /1.html site.com/folder/1
Redirect 301 /2.html site.com/2

I guess using mod_rewrite will be the better option but if mod_rewrite is used for a different filetype, will it at least work? [In a few tests I ran, that did work, only seems to fail with the catchall for .html].

Comment: Yes correct, better to rely on `mod_rewrite` rules only as they are more powerful and feature rich.

Comment: Just make sure **catch-all** rule is the last rule and use only mod_rewrite rules.